# Does latest ejabberd community edition support client cert based auth?

Tags: authentication, ejabberd, sasl

Our application has government requirement for **all** HTTP requests to include SSL client certificate and all application servers to check incoming requests for client certificates.
Does ejabberd *community edition* support c2s certificate auth?

https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/protocols/ says that XEP-0178 on community edition is only implemented for S2S communications, but on https://process-one.net/logs/ejabberd@conference.process-one.net/2018/07/09.html someone called  says,
"'c2s_' is for client auth, as opposed to 's2s_'.  Maybe you've seen old docs that said it's a Business-only feature, this went into the Community Edition at some point."

So, is it in community edition as well?

Comment: That conversation also mentions the commit that implemented the feature, right? https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/8b29af62

Comment: @Badlop - oh, you're right. So, according to https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/8b29af62 client cert based auth is supported in community edition now.  Thank you.
In HTTP-binding request I would need to specify mechanism='EXTERNAL', correct?  (https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0178.html)